# WooCommerce : How to convert wp_price value to a numeric value?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm developing a table with two columns, "State" and "Sales". To get the number in the sales column, I use the wc_price function, which works just fine to output a currency string:

CA         $1,652.13

CO         $515.80

...etc.

I have at least 50 rows, one for each state.

The very last row will output the total of all the dollar amounts from column 2.

I discovered that the actual result from wc_price isn't just a sting, it's a block of html:

```
<bdi>
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
    435.50
</bdi>
```

I tried to get to the actual number within the html, `435.50` using strip_tags:

```
$numeric = strip_tags(wc_price($total)); // result is a simple string, with the $ sign
echo str_replace("$","",$numeric) . "<br>"; // doesn't strip away the $ sign.
$tally = $tally + $numeric; // produces an error, non-numeric value.
```

The error is on the `$tally =` line. This doesn't work in any way. Sure, the html tags are stripped, and I'm left with a string: `$435.50`. In other words, I can't get rid of that danged '$' for some reason. I simply cannot parse, convert, or anything to that currency string. (int), intval($numeric), (float)$numeric, floatval($numeric), etc., none of these work. number_format doesn't work, either.

`Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp-content\plugins\my-custom-plugin\my-custom-plugin.php on line 104`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `floatval()` around your `str_replace` and assign the variable.

```php
    $numeric = strip_tags($html);
    $numeric = floatval(str_replace("$", "", $numeric));
```

See [working example](https://onlinephp.io/c/ab584). It works with 5.6, 7.4 and 8.1.

Comment: If that still doesn't work can you `var_dump($numeric);` and `gettype($numeric)` after you added these steps?

Comment: Ok, changed a couple things, now I no longer get the non-numeric error. The tally still gives me 0, but that's way better than what I was getting. Need to perform a couple more tests...

Comment: What happens is that the `str_replace("$","",$numeric)` does not remove the $ sign for some reason. Even doing a `substr($numeric,1,strlen($numeric))` doesn't remove it. 
After using floatval($numeric), gettype($numeric) reveals it is of type double. Yet, I cannot remove the $.

Comment: Well, I finally got it using your recommendation, but I had to go through another str_replace, because for some strange reason it replaced the '$' with the #36; html entity.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
$regular_price = strip_tags($regular_price);
$sale_price = strip_tags($sale_price);
$regular_price = floatval(str_replace('&#36;', '', $regular_price));
$sale_price = floatval(str_replace("&#36;", "", $sale_price));
```

So this problem occurs when we try to get the price of a variable product.
How ever as shown in the above answer **$** is not getting replaced. Its because the sign is in html character code format. that is **&#36;**

There is one more ans I had tried the preg_replace one but that also dont work. It replaced the **$** sign but the **36** from **&#36;** got in place.

You can just run var_dump($regular_price); You will see it will out put the extra 5 letters.
if the number is $80.00 string must show like this
**string(6) $80.00**

But it will show you this
**string(10) $80.00** because the characters are **&#36;80.00**

Wasted an hour for this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the result, but I think it's possible to have the price without the currecy reading from the documentation of [wp_price](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_price):

```php
$numeric = wp_price($total, array('currency'=>''));
```

However you can have some action that change the comportament of the wc_price function.

Comment: I modified the code, as per your example, but the '$' still shows.